# jQuery and HTML how to use storage in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a question for you.

I have a sidebar with a dropdown "toggle buttons". The code HTML are the following.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-dark sidebar">
       <div class="sidebar-sticky">
         <ul class="nav flex-column">
             <li class="nav-item"  id="sidebar">
                 <a class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1" href="#firstSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse"
                 aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Performance Monitoring<span data-feather="plus-circle"></span></a>
                 <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="firstSubmenu">
                     <li>
                         <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                             <span data-feather="monitor"></span>
                             Dashboard</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         <a class="nav-link" href="/conto_economico">
                             <span data-feather="trending-up"></span>
                             Conto Economico</a>
                     </li>
                    ....
```

All works perfectly, but If I open my dropdown menu and after I update or change the url page, the dropdown menu collapse and I'm force do open it again.

So I looked for a jQuery code that give me the possibility to achive my aim. I fund that it's possibile to use `localStorage` to memorize if a dropdown menu is open or not and when upload the page give the same opened and closed dropdown menu.

I have tried to adapt the code for my aim, but I'm not good at jQuery code. I have tried the following code but does not work

```
  $("#sidebar li a").on("click", function() {
// get index of parent `<li>` within it's siblings
var container = $(this).closest("li");
var selected_item_index = $("#sidebar li").index(container);
localStorage.setItem("sidebar_selected", selected_item_index);
});

$(function() {
    $("#sidebar li").eq(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("selected_item_index "))).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the container as li element and you are trying to find its index in set of anchor element. You need to instead find the index in set of li element. like this

```
var container = $(this).closest("li");
var selected_item_index = $("#sidebar li").index(container);
```

Also, You may want to remove the active class from other sibling elements after setting the li class active using setStorage. Also, the keyname used for getstorage and setstorage are different. They should be same instead

```
 $("#sidebar li").eq(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("sidebar_selected "))).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Comment: I have tried your code but still does not works. I have also updated my answer with your suggestions to check if there are some errors

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco: Can you include the working snippet with minimal HTML and JS above? Can debug and fix issue that way

Comment: Okey @Milind Anantwar I have edit with the full html used and JS. I hope that now it will be possibile to check my error

Comment: The keyname used for setstorage and getstorage are different. It should be same instead

Comment: Could you explain me better modifying your answer?